# Converting React to React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a React App that I need to convert to React Native. I do not have a lot of experience on web development, so i might be missing something essential here. The problem I have is that when I open the app in the emulator I only see a white page that says "Home" on top. This what i have translated of the code so far.

index.js

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Routes from './src/core/Routes';
import configureStore from './src/services/store';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import {createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider} from '@material-ui/core';
import {
    font_family_default,
    font_family_secondary,
    font_size_md,
    font_size_sm,
    font_weight_bold,
    font_weight_normal,
    font_weight_semi_bold,
} from './src/assets/style/variables';
import {rem} from './src/assets/style/functions';
import colors from './src/assets/style/colors';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
    typography: {
        fontFamily: font_family_default,
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeightLight: font_weight_normal,
        fontWeightRegular: font_weight_semi_bold,
        fontWeightMedium: font_weight_bold,
    },
    overrides: {
        MuiMenuItem: {
            root: {
                fontSize: font_size_sm,
                fontFamily: font_family_secondary,
                fontWeight: font_weight_semi_bold,
                minHeight: rem(40),
            },
        },
        MuiMenu: {
            paper: {
                boxShadow: '0px 12px 56px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
                borderRadius: `${rem(3)}`,
            },
        },
        MuiExpansionPanelSummary: {
            root: {
                padding: `0px ${rem(16)}`,
            },
            content: {
                margin: `${rem(8)} 0px `,
            },
        },
        MuiInputBase: {
            root: {
                fontSize: font_size_md,
            },
        },
        MuiPickersToolbar: {
            toolbar: {
                backgroundColor: colors.grey.primary,
            },
        },
        MuiPickersDay: {
            daySelected: {
                backgroundColor: colors.yellow.dark2,
                '&:hover': {
                    backgroundColor: colors.yellow.dark2,
                },
            },
        },

        MuiPickersClockNumber: {
            clockNumberSelected: {backgroundColor: colors.yellow.dark2},
        },

        MuiPickersClock: {
            pin: {backgroundColor: colors.yellow.dark2},
        },
        MuiPickersClockPointer: {
            pointer: {backgroundColor: colors.yellow.dark2},
            thumb: {border: `14px solid ${colors.yellow.dark2}`},
        },
    },
});

const store = configureStore();

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                    <Routes/>
                </View>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        </Provider>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Router, Scene} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import Login from '../pages/login';

const Routes = () => (
    <Router>
        <Scene key="root">
            <Scene key="home" component={Login} title="Home" initial={true}/>
        </Scene>
    </Router>
);

export default Routes;
```

/src/page/login/index.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';
import Input from '../../shared/components/Input';
import Button from '../../shared/components/Button';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {APP_ROUTES} from '../../core/global-constants';
import {Link, Redirect} from 'react-router-native';

import Logo from '../../assets/img/log.svg';
import colors from '../../assets/style/colors';
import {rem} from '../../assets/style/functions';
import {device, font_size_md, font_size_xxl, font_weight_normal} from '../../assets/style/variables';
import {login} from '../../services/actions/authenticationActions';
import useForm from '../../shared/hooks/useForm';
import validate from './loginFormValidations';

const theme = {
    backgroundColor: colors.white.light1,
};

function Login(props) {
    const {values, handleChange, handleSubmit, errors} = useForm(login, validate);
    const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);
    const [errorLogin, setErrorLogin] = useState(false);

    function login() {
        if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0) {
            props.login(values).then(
                res => {
                    setRedirect(true);
                },
                err => {
                    errors.login = props.errorMessage
                        ? `${props.errorMessage},  please try again`
                        : `No active account found with the given credentials,  please try again`;
                    setErrorLogin(true);
                },
            );
        }
    }

    if (redirect) {
        return <Redirect to={APP_ROUTES.timeTracker}/>;
    }
    return (
        <Style.Section>
            <Style.Img src={Logo} alt="toki timer logo"/>
            <Style.Hero>
                <Style.Title>Welcome back!</Style.Title>
                <Style.Subtitle>Log in to continue</Style.Subtitle>
            </Style.Hero>
            <Style.Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Style.FormGroup>
                    <Input
                        id="username"
                        name="username"
                        placeholder="Username"
                        backgroundColor={theme}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        value={values.username || ''}
                        hasError={errors.username}
                    />
                    {errors.username && <Style.ErrorMessage>{errors.username}</Style.ErrorMessage>}
                </Style.FormGroup>

                <Style.FormGroup>
                    <Input
                        id="password"
                        name="password"
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="Password"
                        backgroundColor={theme}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        value={values.password || ''}
                        hasError={errors.password}
                    />
                    {errors.password && <Style.ErrorMessage>{errors.password}</Style.ErrorMessage>}
                    {errorLogin && <Style.ErrorMessage>{errors.login}</Style.ErrorMessage>}
                </Style.FormGroup>
                <Button name="Login" type="submit"/>
            </Style.Form>
            <Style.Hero>
                <Style.BottomLinks>
                    <Style.Link to={APP_ROUTES.forgotPassword}>Forgot your password?</Style.Link>
                </Style.BottomLinks>
            </Style.Hero>
        </Style.Section>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        loading: state.authorization.loading,
        isAuthenticated: state.authorization.isAuthenticated,
        loginSuccess: state.authorization.loginSuccess,
        loginError: state.authorization.loginError,
        errorMessage: state.authorization.errorMessage,
        isAdmin: state.authorization.userInSession.isAdmin,
    };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = {login};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
)(Login);

const Style = {};

Style.Section = styled.SectionList`
  background-color: ${colors.grey.primary};
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`;
Style.Form = styled.View`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 35%;
  margin-bottom: ${rem(40)};

  @media ${device.mobileS} {
    padding: 0 5%;
  }

  @media ${device.mobileL} {
    padding: 0 15%;
  }

  @media ${device.laptop} {
    padding: 0 35%;
  }
`;

Style.Hero = styled.View`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: ${rem(70)};
  align-items: center;
`;
Style.Title = styled.Text`
  color: ${colors.white.primary};
  font-size: ${font_size_xxl};
  font-weight: ${font_weight_normal};
  margin: 0;
`;
Style.Subtitle = styled(Style.Title)`
  font-size: ${font_size_md};
`;
Style.Img = styled.Image`
  margin-bottom: ${rem(60)};
  margin-top: ${rem(60)};
`;
Style.BottomLinks = styled.Text`
  color: ${colors.white.primary};
  margin-top: ${rem(10)};
`;

Style.Link = styled(Link)`
  color: ${colors.yellow.primary};

  &:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
`;
Style.FormGroup = styled.View`
  margin-bottom: ${rem(45)};
`;
Style.ErrorMessage = styled.Text`
  font-size: ${font_size_md};
  color: ${colors.red.primary};
`;
```

What I don't seem to understand after reading documentation is how routing works, for example, using react, my Routes.js looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import { APP_ROUTES } from './global-constants'
import Login from '../pages/login'
import Dashboard from '../pages/dashboard'
import TimeTracker from '../pages/time-tracker'
import SignUp from '../pages/signUp'
import PrivateRoute from '../shared/components/PrivateRoute'
import UserList from '../pages/user-list'
import DepartmentsList from '../pages/departments-list'
import Reports from '../pages/reports'
import UserProfile from '../pages/user-profile'
import ForgotPassword from '../pages/forgot-password'
import NotFound from '../shared/components/NotFound'

const Routes = () => (
  <main>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={[APP_ROUTES.home, APP_ROUTES.login]} component={Login} />
      <Route exact path={APP_ROUTES.signUp} component={SignUp} />
      <Route exact path={APP_ROUTES.forgotPassword} component={ForgotPassword} />
      <PrivateRoute
        exact
        path={[APP_ROUTES.dashboard, APP_ROUTES.dashboardDeparment]}
        component={Dashboard}
      />
      <PrivateRoute exact path={APP_ROUTES.timeTracker} component={TimeTracker} />
      <PrivateRoute exact path={APP_ROUTES.usersList} component={UserList} />
      <PrivateRoute exact path={APP_ROUTES.departments} component={DepartmentsList} />
      <PrivateRoute exact path={APP_ROUTES.reports} component={Reports} />
      <PrivateRoute exact path={APP_ROUTES.userDetails} component={UserProfile} />
      <PrivateRoute component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  </main>
)

export default Routes
```

I made the changes to the routes file since I've read that react-router-dom does not work in native. My main purpose is to re-use as much code as possible, but if I can't, what do I need to change for the page to actually show in the emulator?

Comment: React Native is not web based, it's native based, it has its' own native components. There is no HTML elements nor routes. I am not aware of any easy method to convert React to React Native. There is [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) but that's for making RN apps play on web browsers.

Comment: although it doesn't give good feeling to users , you can use webview https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html

Comment: Unfortunately there are no way to convert web code to mobile. You need to convert things manually. Fyi: You can use react-router on native too (I saw react-router-native package on its website). But don't recommend it personally. Use `react-navigation` library instead.

Answer (score 20):

If you want to move your App from React Web application to React Native App, then you can reuse your functionality, Components, lifecycle methods, `setState`, props, but you have to write your return (*render*) method code in respective to React Native, because in React Web application the HTML code also works fine but in mobile app, you need to add `<View>` to design your UI similar to `<div>`.

For Mobile App, we also need to handle gestures as `onPress` instead of `onClick`. And instead of Routing, you need to add Navigator `Stack Navigator`, `Drawer Navigator`, `Tab Navigator` according to your requirements.

Please refer to [React Native Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started) and for navigation 
 [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html).

Answer (score 3):

You will have to manually make changes to the code in order to make it work with react-native. We dont have this much of similarity to make React work with React native. You will have to use the native elements for it work.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reuse the 'Render' part of React (Web) into his Native Solution, because it uses a different approvach to generate the views. At first glance they looks, as both uses the same syntactic format, implementing "Tags" for generate the render tree.

But the difference here is that both solutions differs on how those "Tags" are implemented. While React (Web) translate them to the well know HTML5 Standard tags, the "Native" translate those to equivalent platform-native components. For this reason, they must be very abstract to provide an adequate abstraction layer to achieve the "Single Codebase / Multiplatform" premise.

The concept of Components, Props and States keeps intact. Also, the 'Style' logic [isn't the same](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style) (Although is kinda CSS inspired)

Making some research i found that the 'Material-UI' Library is only React (Web) supported, so you must migrate to another solution to apply the desired UI Style. I would recommend search on [Awesome React Native](https://www.awesome-react-native.com/) which is an curated index for some of the most popular React Native Components.

About the Routing part, you're using two different libraries: 'react-router-dom' and 'react-native-router-flux'. The first one isn't Native Compatible, but haves a [compatible version](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/native/). However, you'll must discard one of them to avoid collitions.

Also i recommend you this 'React to React Native' Article which provides some important aspects to consider through the migration process:
[From React to React Native — What you need to know to jump ship](https://itnext.io/from-react-to-react-native-what-you-need-to-know-to-jump-ship-61320df96557)

Answer (score 0):

> You have to write the code separately because there are lot of
>   difference between reactjs and react native. For example in reactjs we
>   are using div tag and in react native its view tag and the codes are
>   entirely different.